# Karate Mock Static Method call

Tags: karate

How do we mock a static method from `Karate` runner, so that the mocked static method is called instead of the actual static method.

While I agree we should have had testable code without static method call, it is not always possible :)

Can `Mockito` be used along with `Karate` feature to mock the static method call? Thanks

Comment: this is interesting, are you actually using karate for unit testing ? anyway I personally don't know of a solution here, but do contribute your findings back as an answer if possible

Comment: Couldn't find a way to get it working, it is part of Integration Testing only however due to some limitations from the build environment, this has to be mocked. Can you please consider this as a feature request?